# Trivial edit spree by new user - get's all of it approved

Tags: support, new-users, review-abuse

See [this user's rep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5046766/0mf?tab=reputation) - all of them are trivial edits that get approved one after the other. <s>There is something wrong with current reviews</s>.

Edit:
Seems all edits are only approved by [the same user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4839862/fpj).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Move along folks, nothing to see here...

(Next time, just flag - the mods will investigate and Take Action as needed)

Comment: So my rollbacks did not trigger anything?

Comment: Nothing interesting.